# Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice in magento

Tags: magento, backend

When I click on a product in my Magento site I get this error:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Invalid backend model specified: `catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice`
>
> Trace:
>
> ```
> #0 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Abstract.php(338): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
> #1 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(596): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
> #2 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(1425): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)
> #3 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(877): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterLoad(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
> #4 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Abstract.php(630): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 309, NULL)
> #5 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 309, NULL)
> #6 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\ProductController.php(52): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(309)
> #7 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\ProductController.php(138): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->_initProduct()
> #8 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
> #9 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
> #10 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #11 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #12 F:\wamp\www\bc\app\Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #13 F:\wamp\www\bc\index.php(103): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #14 {main}
> ```
>
> Error log record number: 1257579136

What is this?
How can I solve this?

My Magento version is 1.4.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I think it should have returned the row of an attribute for which you have assigned the backend model as `catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice`.

When you assign the value as `catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice`, it will be expecting a file `groupprice.php` in the

```
app/code/core/mage/catalog/product/attribute/model/backend/groupprice.php
```

If this is not present it throws error. So you need to create a new backend model.
Create a new Module in your local folder app/code/local/Newmodule and create a `.php` file named "GroupPrice" under the folder

```
app/code/local/Newmodule/product/attribute/model/backend/groupprice.php
```

I am not sure about the business logic of your attribute, so I will not be able to help you further. But you can take a look [HERE](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/using-a-backend-model-to-customize-magento-a-tip-from-magento-developers-paradise/).

Comment: i created a folder as groupprice in local and created a php file in local/groupprice/model.Then what i do?

Comment: There are three points you have to understand 1. What is the backend model and how is it used for product attribute 2. What is the use of your attribute groupprice (assuming it as groupprice from  your question ) 3.How does the default backend model  works (take a look at the app/code/core/mage/catalog/product/attribute/model/backend/price.php..sorry could not edit my previous comment, time passed away

Comment: If the class is missing and it isn't yours, check if the extension that it belongs to is still present in the codebase. If not, the locate it and remove it since you will not need it, aka you have stuff in database that never will be used. 
How to remove: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/delete-custom-eav-attributes-from-the-database

Answer (score 0):

I think the value for the column "backend_model" of the "eav_attribute" table for a particular attribute of the product(in your case I am guessing something related to groupprice) has been assigned invalid value of "catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice", which may not be existing. 
If you are creating a customised backend model, then  you must have a class called CustomModule_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_GroupPrice in your CustomModule.

Hope it makes sense

Comment: can youn explain how can i do this?

Comment: i put a query in phpmyadmin as `SELECT *
FROM 'eav_attribute'
WHERE 'backend_model' = "catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice"` ,then i got result with that class name.

Comment: I think it should have returned the row of an attribute for which you have assigned the backend model as "catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice".

Comment: then what i do here?Give a solution clearly,Iam new in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs when some essential database entries from the magento database goes missing. It is thus advised to back up **ALL** the data prior to performing any such operation.

In my case, I was testing upgrading the magento codebase from 1.6.x to 1.7.y and the upgrade caused some changes in the magento database. I restored my database to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also this kind of error may indicate invalid Magento installation. For example not not all files were uploaded or not all files are accessible because of incorrect file permissions on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the following commands hope it will solve your problem

```
chmod 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ pub/media/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ pub/media/
```